# error build all ros packages in this repo the error occur in catkin_make step

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ros, ignition, gazebo-simu

I followed [instruction by Michael Huang](https://github.com/michaelhuang14/quadevac_sim_ws).

My error message reads:

> In file included from /home/evadro/quadevac_sim_ws/catkin_ws/src/menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/include/MengeCong.h:10:0,
>                    from /home/evadro/quadevac_sim_ws/catkin_ws/src/menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/src/MengeCong.cpp:8:
>   /home/evadro/quadevac_sim_ws/catkin_ws/src/menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/../menge_common/include/MengePlugin.h:13:44: fatal error: gazebo/physics/InstancedActor.hh: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/CMakeFiles/menge_congregate.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/CMakeFiles/menge_congregate.dir/src/MengeCong.cpp.o' failed
>   make[2]: *** [menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/CMakeFiles/menge_congregate.dir/src/MengeCong.cpp.o] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4099: recipe for target 'menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/CMakeFiles/menge_congregate.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: *** [menge_gazebo/menge_congregate/CMakeFiles/menge_congregate.dir/all]

The 2nd error is:

> make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>
> Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2
>
> Invoking "make -j24 -l24" failed

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please quote here what you have used from the linked resource.

Comment: I follow the Steps to Build and Run and i stopped at step number 5 in catkin_make

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is `gazebo/physics/InstancedActor.hh  No such file or directory`.

this header is not on standard version of Gazebo.
Make Sure you Compiled Gazebo Repo mentioned in `External Depenencies` [Here](https://bitbucket.org/michaelhuang16/gazebo) with No errors. Then Double checks paths so compiler can find the missing headers.

Comment: Hi mr.Mohammed Ali thank you for replying 
I'm following this github page https://github.com/michaelhuang14/quadevac_sim_ws to build the integration between ROS , Gazebo and Menge to simulate crowed evacuation 
I reached to step 7
 I'm trying to solve it becuase my graduation project rely on it and I try to communicate with Mr.michel but I couldn't find any response 
so if you have any plan could help us please contact us 



thank you indeed

Comment: Have You compiled the custom version of gazebo mentioned in [step 1](https://bitbucket.org/michaelhuang16/gazebo/src/default) `of External Dependencies section` ? your step 7 is stuck because it needs a header file from that repository.